# Escaping photo caption to avoid cross site script attack

Tags: php, beginner, html, security, escaping

I am a PHP newbie and this is part of a gallery code. I recently read about SQL injection and cross site scripting attack, I am trying to avoid that by html escaping on dynamically produced data. I am not sure if I am heading in the right direction here. I created an array with URL parameters then a function for HTML escaping. Can you critique this code and let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
$parameters_new = array('name' => $name,'pcaption' => $caption_array[$new]);

function html_escape($input, $encoding)
{
    return htmlentities($input, ENT_QUOTES, $encoding);
}

$result_final .= '<div class="limage"><table><tr><td><table class="image"><tr><td><a href="' . html_escape('gallery.php?' . http_build_query($parameters_new), 'UTF-8') . '">
<img src="'. $img_dir . '/' .$photo_filename.'"  alt=" ' . $photo_keywords . '"></a>
<div class="caption">'.$photo_caption.'</div><div class="excerpt">'.$photo_description.'</div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><div class="underline"></div>;
```

Comment: Given that the href attribute can't possibly contain `<` and `>` (at least not AFAIK), `strip_tags` seems like a valid contender. Also: `http_build_query` + additional escaping might put you at risk for double encoded values (like ` ` => `%20` => `%2520`), so be careful

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a one size fits all approach, you can filter things based on what they are.

- URLs and url parameters can be encoded with urlencode()
- Output inside of html tags can be filtered with strip_tags()
- Other more general output that you are using with HTML attributes such as 'alt' are less predictable, and can be filtered with htmlentities()